# 2D Platformer Collision Handling

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d, sdl, collision-detection

I am trying to create a 2D platformer (Mario-type) game and I am some having some issues with handling collisions properly. I am writing this game in C++, using SDL for input, image loading, font loading, etcetera. I am also using OpenGL via the FreeGLUT library in conjunction with SDL to display graphics.

My method of collision detection is AABB (Axis-Aligned Bounding Box), which is really all I need to start with. What I need is an easy way to both detect which side the collision occurred on and handle the collisions properly. So, basically, if the player collides with the top of the platform, reposition him to the top; if there is a collision to the sides, reposition the player back to the side of the object; if there is a collision to the bottom, reposition the player under the platform.

I have tried ***many*** different ways of doing this, such as trying to find the penetration depth and repositioning the player backwards by the penetration depth. Sadly, nothing I've tried seems to work correctly. Player movement ends up being very glitchy and repositions the player when I don't want it to. Part of the reason is probably because I feel like this is something so simple but I'm over-thinking it.

If anyone thinks they can help, please take a look at the code below and help me try to improve on this if you can. I would like to refrain from using a library to handle this (as I want to learn on my own) or the something like the SAT (Separating Axis Theorem) if at all possible. Thank you in advance for your help!

```
void world1Level1CollisionDetection()
{
for(int i; i < blocks; i++)
{
    if (de2dCheckCollision(ball,block[i],0.0f,0.0f)==true)
    {
        de2dObj ballPrev;
        ballPrev.coords[0] = ball.coords[0];
        ballPrev.coords[1] = ball.coords[1];
        ballPrev.coords[2] = ball.coords[2];
        ballPrev.coords[3] = ball.coords[3];
        ballPrev.coords[0] -= ball.xspeed;
        ballPrev.coords[1] -= ball.yspeed;
        ballPrev.coords[2] -= ball.xspeed;
        ballPrev.coords[3] -= ball.yspeed;

        int up = 0;
        int left = 0;
        int right = 0;
        int down = 0;

        if (ballPrev.coords[0] < block[i].coords[0] && ballPrev.coords[2] < block[i].coords[0] && (((ball.coords[1] < block[i].coords[1]) || (ball.coords[3] < ball.coords[1]))  || ((ball.coords[1] < block[i].coords[3]) || ball.coords[3] < block[i].coords[3])))
        {
            left = 1;
        }

        if (ballPrev.coords[0] > block[i].coords[2] && ballPrev.coords[2] > block[i].coords[2] && (((ball.coords[1] < block[i].coords[1]) || (ball.coords[3] < ball.coords[1]))  || ((ball.coords[1] < block[i].coords[3]) || (ball.coords[3] < block[i].coords[3]))))
        {
            right = 1;
        }
        if(ballPrev.coords[1] < block[i].coords[1] && block[i].coords[1] < ballPrev.coords[3] && ballPrev.coords[3] < block[i].coords[3])
        {
            up = 1;
        }
        if(block[i].coords[1] < ballPrev.coords[1] && ballPrev.coords[1] < block[i].coords[3] && block[i].coords[3] < ballPrev.coords[3])
        {
            down = 1;
        }

        cout << left << ", " << right << ", " << up << ", " << down << ", " << endl;

        if (left == 1)
        {
            ball.coords[0] = block[i].coords[0] - 18.0f;
            ball.coords[2] = block[i].coords[0] - 2.0f;
        }
        else if (right == 1)
        {
            ball.coords[0] = block[i].coords[2] + 2.0f;
            ball.coords[2] = block[i].coords[2] + 18.0f;
        }
        else if (down == 1)
        {
            ball.coords[1] = block[i].coords[3] + 4.0f;
            ball.coords[3] = block[i].coords[3] + 20.0f;
        }
        else if (up == 1)
        {
            ball.yspeed = 0.0f;
            ball.gravity = 0.0f;
            ball.coords[1] = block[i].coords[1] - 17.0f;
            ball.coords[3] = block[i].coords[1] - 1.0f;
        }
    }
    if (de2dCheckCollision(ball,block[i],0.0f,0.0f)==false)
    {
        ball.gravity = -0.5f;
    }
}
}
```

To explain what some of this code means:

The blocks variable is basically an integer that is storing the amount of blocks, or platforms. I am checking all of the blocks using a for loop, and the number that the loop is currently on is represented by integer i.
The coordinate system might seem a little weird, so that's worth explaining.
coords[0] represents the x position (left) of the object (where it starts on the x axis).
coords[1] represents the y position (top) of the object (where it starts on the y axis).
coords[2] represents the width of the object plus coords[0] (right).
coords[3] represents the height of the object plus coords[1] (bottom).
de2dCheckCollision performs an AABB collision detection.
Up is negative y and down is positive y, as it is in most games.

Hopefully I have provided enough information for someone to help me successfully. If there is something I left out that might be crucial, let me know and I'll provide the necessary information. Finally, for anyone who can help, providing code would be very helpful and much appreciated.

Thank you again for your help!

**Edit 2**: I have updated my code with a new algorithm that checks where the ball was previously before collision. Corner cases work on that single platform correctly now, and when I have a wall of objects, I *can* slide against it correctly now. The only remaining problem is that there is a small jittering effect that happens when I am on the ground, where the ball is constantly going up and down as if it is being pulled by gravity and then the ball falls back into the object again.

**Edit**: Here is a URL to an image trying to show the kinds of problems I am having:
http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/4603/collisionproblem.png

In case the explanation in the picture doesn't make too much sense, the ball cannot move left past the corner of an object unless I jump over it. However, the ball *can* move right, but it gets repositioned to the right of the object *while moving*, which is not needed. This creates a skipping movement essentially, where it appears as the the ball is skipping over half of the object or so when I move right. If this doesn't make sense, please ask me and I'll try to clarify more.

Comment: This question might be better suited for gamedev.stackexchange.com, however... the population there seems lacking in various respects. Might be better off here after all.

Comment: For what it's worth, movement code in platformers does contain a lot of hand-tuning and glitches.  There's even a community of people who reverse-engineer those to make "tool-assisted speedruns".

Comment: I've heard of "tool-assisted speedruns before". Thanks for the heads up about platformer movement code. It seems that I'd need to do a ***lot*** of hand-tuning to get this to work properly. Hopefully someone will have some ideas as to how I can fix this issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One problem with your code is that you only detect situations like this:

[image: ball]

If the circle happens to be fully inside the block, you don't reposition at all. And that's a problem.

You're trying to think about your simulation as if it were continuous, but keep in mind it's discrete. In general, if you *only* look at the current state of the ball, you really cannot know which side it collided with. Look at these two possibilities:
[image: cases]

The first solution that comes to mind is to look at the *last* position of the ball as well; more precisely, look at the delta vector. See if the delta vector intersects a wall. If it does, reposition in an axis-aligned direction towards the wall intersected by the delta vector.

**Edit:** When I said "delta vector", I forgot that you're moving a square and not a single point. So, if you just look at the delta vector of the top-left corner, that's not going to be enough because it may not detect that part of the ball entered a block. Instead, you can look at the delta vectors of all 4 corners.

Comment: +1 for going so far as to illustrate the solution. Was in the process my self.

Comment: I see. So if I'm understanding this correctly, check where the ball was before the actual collision and try handling it accordingly, correct? One of the big issues I have though, is handling on multiple axis, and when the object hits a corner.

Comment: @defender-zone: You've understood me correctly. I don't know what you mean "handling on multiple axis" - the delta vector solutions works fine both in the x and the y direction. About the corner case - do you want your ball to be circular in the physics simulation, or just an axis-aligned square?

Comment: @Stefan Monov: I thought if the object hit a corner, it would be some different scenario. Thank you for clearing this doubt up for me. Also, my ball is just an axis-aligned square. I'll try to start incorporating your suggestions into my code. Thank you very much for the help. I appreciate it.

Comment: @defender-zone: Draw this stuff on paper - should make it clearer. For the corner case - think about it like this: what will the new algorithm do in case of a corner collision? It will pick a wall to slide against, and it will slide against it. Which one from the 2 corner walls will it pick? Draw a couple of cases on paper and you'll see it picks the correct wall (kinda hard to explain but you can prove it rigorously yourself, or ask for more help if you can't). Also, I edited my answer to include some more info.

Comment: So in a corner collision you need the same behavior as in an edge collision. No special case.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this for me. I just can't seem to think of a decent algorithm that I can use to detect which side the collision occurred on. I keep thinking that 2 cases will return true and cause problems. Are there some simple changes I can make to my existing algorithm, or would I have to rewrite a new one?

Comment: 2 cases? You mean 2 of the 4 cases that I mentioned in the edit? Yes, they sometimes will. Ok, let's say you check the 4 delta vectors and find n intersections (n can be > 4 if you pass through the entire block). The trick is that *one* of the n intersections happened first. Which one? Well, all 4 corners move with the same speed. So, dividing distance by speed, you get time. So the first collision has happened at the intersection closest to its position in the last frame. Ok, now that you know where the collision occurred, you know which wall you should slide against.

Comment: Ah, this is starting to make sense to me now. A possible flaw that _I_ would see would be a case where you are walking on the ground. What I've experienced from previous attempts of mine is that when I reach the end of an object that is part of the floor, the ball cannot move past it and it is bound to the x distance of that one smaller object. So, in this case, my ball is technically coming from the side before a collision occurs, and the algorithm would want to reposition it on the x axis first. Tell me if this does not make sense and I'll try to explain more.

Comment: I don't get it. Post a pic. Mostly I don't get why you're getting repositioned on the x axis if you didn't collide with any vertical wall.

Comment: I just posted the picture. Please note that I haven't incorporated your ideas yet, as I am still a little bit confused on how to do it properly. Hopefully this picture will clear things up a little bit.

Comment: In case the explanation in the picture doesn't make too much sense, the ball cannot move left past the corner of an object unless I jump over it. However, the ball _can_ move right, but it gets repositioned to the right of the object _while moving_, which is not needed. This creates a skipping movement essentially, where it appears as the the ball is skipping over half of the object or so when I move right. If this doesn't make sense, please ask me and I'll try to clarify more.

Comment: @defender-zone: Seems like de2dCheckCollision returns true for edge cases where the topmost coord of one rectangle is equal to the bottommost coord of the other rectangle. It should return false for such cases.

Comment: @Stefan Monov: Ah, yes, that is what that function is currently doing - returning true for edge cases. I have been drawing this out on paper like you suggested and I am starting to understand it better. I am not at home right now, so I don't have a computer to test this on. Just to confirm: I am to check where the object was before the collision took place, and if, say, it was above the platform, reposition it only upwards, correct? And same goes for other cases?

Comment: @Stefan Monov: After trying to write an algorithm that checks where the ball was before a collision, I am _still_ having issues. I posted my new code above to kind of give you an idea of what I am trying to do. Corner cases work on that single platform correctly now, and when I have a wall of objects, I _can_ slide against it correctly now. The only remaining problem is that there is a small jittering effect that happens when I am on the ground, where the ball is constantly going up and down as if it is being pulled by gravity and then the ball falls back into the object again. Any ideas?

Comment: Whoa. An if condition with nesting and 5 logical operators? And with [0][1][2][3] indexing instead of normal .x1, .x2, .y1, .y2 members in a struct? I'm not even gonna try to read that. But about the jittering: Does the ball ever visibly intersect the block, or does it just bounce on top of it?

Comment: I know - my code is messy. The ball is just bouncing on top of the block, not intersecting it. I can fix this issue by moving the ball 1 pixel deep into the block on the y axis. Not exactly the solution I was hoping for, but I guess I can deal with it. It seems to me that this is happening because de2dCheckCollision doesn't check edge cases (It actually didn't even do this before; my mistake). If you have a better solution, please let me know. I have marked this post as the answer. Thank you so much for the help you have given me. I really do appreciate it. You have gotten me to a great start.

Comment: @defender-zone: Your biggest problem is that you don't actually know what your code does. I can see that from your posts. You should learn to debug this sort of simple code. Precondition: `ball.y2==block.y1`. Physics does `ball.y+=delta` due to gravity and `ball.y-=delta` due to repositioning. Postcondition: `ball.y2==block.y1`. Given this, you insert debug prints to verify the precondition, the postcondition, the assumption that gravity adds delta, and the assumption that repositioning substracts (the same) delta. Then the bug's cause will be apparent.

Comment: @defender-zone: Using a systematic approach means that given enough time, you'll be able to solve any bug and all that's left will be conceptual issues. What you shouldn't do is start changing code based on some vague hunch of what may be wrong. It would help to get a mentor - someone experienced to work with, so you pick up good methodology from him.

Comment: @Stefan Monov: Yes, I'll admit it: I've been basically throwing semi-random code together in rapid succession to see if something would work or not. That has only seemed to cause me frustration. I _should_ be taking a systematic approach instead of throwing code together, but I guess I was becoming impatient with the issue, since I have been spending weeks trying to fix it. Well, thanks for the advice, and the explanation about how to debug my code in a better way.